# Recover fees associated with car being impounded

Tags: canada, traffic, british-columbia

In British Columbia, there is an excessive speeding law where you get a ticket and your car is automatically impounded for 7 days. If you dispute the ticket and win, you do not pay the ticket but you do not get to recover the money paid to the towing company, nor do you get to recover costs associated with finding alternate transportation (like a rental car, bus fare, etc).

I am curious as to why this is the case. If you dispute the ticket and win, does that not mean that the government erred in giving you the ticket and do you not have a case against the government to recover costs incurred because of their error?

Comment: ...what on earth is an *excessive driving* law?

Comment: For more information: https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/transportation/driving-and-cycling/road-safety-rules-and-consequences/vehicle-impoundment

Answer (score 1):

I can’t speak for this BC law in particular but, in general, the government is not liable for any costs you incur in defending yourself against a prosecution *unless* that prosecution was malicious.